# "Unix syslog delivery error" in debian docker image

Tags: docker

I am getting error "Unix syslog delivery error" when i run my docker image through kubernetes.
My dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM debian:jessie
EXPOSE 3307
COPY maven /abc/
WORKDIR /abc
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssl libssl-dev libgssapi-krb5-2 syslog-ng-core && adduser user1 && chown -R user1 /abc
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","/abc/run.sh"]
USER abc
```

and my run.sh is below

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod 755 /abc/mongosqld
/abc/mongosqld --schema /abc/rmg.drdl --mongo-uri mongodb://10.*.*.*:4232 --auth --mongo-username admin --mongo-password admin --sslPEMKeyFile=/abc/mongosqld-server.pem --sslMode allowSSL --quiet
```

Please let me know how to resolve this.

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 3):

I was deploying the image through kubernetes. And it is resolved by installing rsyslog in the RUN command and starting syslog before running the mongosqld process.my run.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod 755 /abc/mongosqld
echo "password" | sudo -S service rsyslog start
ln -s /dev/stdout /log/sqld.log
/abc/mongosqld --schema /abc/rmg.drdl --mongo-uri mongodb://10.*.*.*:4232 --auth --mongo-username admin --mongo-password admin --sslPEMKeyFile=/abc/mongosqld-server.pem --sslMode allowSSL --logAppend --logRotate=reopen --logPath=/log/sqld.log
```

my dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie
EXPOSE 3307
COPY maven /abc/
WORKDIR /abc
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssl libssl-dev libgssapi-krb5-2 rsyslog && adduser user1 && chown -R user1 /abc
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","/abc/run.sh"]
USER abc
```

Comment: Hi @dutt, is it possible to run mongosqld without rsyslog?

Comment: Hi @LucaAnceschi : Not sure whether rsyslog is mandatory to run mongosqld or not. But for the error("Unix syslog delivery error") I was receiving I had to run this service before running mongosqld.